_webservices__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.GetCategorie(...) is undefined error
I'm developing a REACT.js site. This site queues a server to get data to display via fetch() primitive.
App.js:
    import { GetTornei, GetCategorie } from './webservices';
    import './App.css';
    import { Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

    function App() {

      const onCategClick = (idTorneo) => {
      console.log("[App] onCategClick idTorneo="+idTorneo)
      GetCategorie(idTorneo).then((data) => {
        console.log("onCat: ",data)
        navigate("categorie", { state: data.list })
      })
      }

...
      <Button style={{margin: '2px'}} variant='outlined' onClick={() => onCategClick(AnnoTorneo)}>Lista categorie</Button>
...


In the webservices.js I have a set of exported functions:
export function GetCategorie (idTorneo)
  {
      console.log("[ws] GetCategorie "+idTorneo)
      let param = new URLSearchParams({idTorneo})
      fetch(BaseUrl+"/GetCategorie.php?" + param,
        {
          method: "GET",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {}
        }
      ).then((response)=> response.json()
      ).then((data)=>{
        console.log("[ws] GetCategorie: ",data)
        return data
      })
  }

When I press the button I have a webpage showing 3 times:
ERROR
_webservices__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.GetCategorie(...) is undefined
onCategClick@http://localhost:3000/main.78b5d0e5441e18c64719.hot-update.js:67:63
onClick@http://localhost:3000/main.78b5d0e5441e18c64719.hot-update.js:158:34
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32072:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32116:20
...

In the console window I see the following outputs:
[App] onCategClick idTorneo=2020 App.js:36

[ws] GetCategorie 2020 webservices.js:45

Uncaught TypeError: _webservices__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.GetCategorie(...) is undefined
    onCategClick App.js:37
    onClick App.js:68
    React 15
 App.js:37
    onCategClick App.js:37
    onClick App.js:68
    React 15

XHR GET
https://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/Torneo/1.1/GetCategorie.php?idTorneo=2020
[HTTP/3 200 OK 158ms]

[ws] GetCategorie:  
Object { ret: "ok", list: (2) […] }

What does it mean?
There are 2 errors @ app.js 37 (????)
The function is found, recalled and it return the correct data!

Finally I rewrote the functions in async ways:
import { GetTornei, GetCategorie } from './webservices';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  const onCategClick = (idTorneo) => {
  console.log("[App] onCategClick idTorneo="+idTorneo)
  const data = await GetCategorie(idTorneo) 
  console.log("[ws] GetCategorie: data: ",data)
  navigate("/categorie", { state: data.list })
  }

...
  <Button style={{margin: '2px'}} variant='outlined' onClick={() => onCategClick(AnnoTorneo)}>Lista categorie</Button>
...

and the query function is:
export async function GetCategorie  (idTorneo) 
{
  console.log("[ws] GetCategorie idTorneo: "+idTorneo)
  let param = new URLSearchParams({idTorneo})
  const response = await fetch(BaseUrl+"/GetCategorie.php?" + param,
    {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {}
    }
  )
  
  console.log("[ws] GetCategorie res: ", response)
  const data = await response.json()
  return data
}

In this way the flow is running as expected.
Is there a better way?
